# How do I handle a configuration class that are loaded at runtime with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection

I'm currently trying to work with dependency injection and so far I love. But it's one thing I can't really get my head around and where my current solution just seems wrong.

I'm working with WPF, MVVM and many of the classes I inject need an instance of a project configuration class that isn't initialized until the user create or open a new project in the application.

So my current solution is to have a "ConfigurationHandler" with load/save method and a property that hold an instance of the configuration class after it's loaded. I inject ConfigurationHandler to the others classes and then they can access the configuration after it's loaded. But it seems weird to let classes that never should save/load configuration handle the whole "ConfigurationHandler" and 100% they would just use it to access the configuration instance likt this:

```
var configuration = configurationHandler.Configuration;
```

Another problem is that if they try to access the configuration before it's loaded they will get exception (should not really happen as you can't do anything before a project is created/loaded, but still).

But the only other solution I can think of is to use "intialize" methods after a project is created/open but that seems just as bad.

So how do you usually handle cases like this?

Edit: Should add that this configuration class handle information like project path, project name, etc so have nothing to do with the dependency injection itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Constructor Injection, consider using an `Ambient Context` approach.

> The last type of DI we’ll discuss is making dependencies available
>   through a static accessor. It is also called injection through the
>   ambient context. It is used when implementing cross-cutting concerns.

This is a good option if the classes that need access to your configuration are of different types in different layers or libraries - i.e. is a true cross-cutting concern.

([Quote source](http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/08/29/solid-design-principles-in-net-the-dependency-inversion-principle-part-2-di-patterns/))

---

### Example, <sub>based on the classic Time Provider one from [Dependency Injection in .NET][2]</sub>

```
abstract class CustomConfiguration
{
    //current dependency stored in static field
    private static CustomConfiguration current;

    //static property which gives access to dependency
    public static CustomConfiguration Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (current == null)
            {
                //Ambient Context can't return null, so we assign a Local Default
                current = new DefaultCustomConfiguration();
            }

            return current;
        }

        set
        {
            //allows to set different implementation of abstraction than Local Default
            current = (value == null) ? new DefaultCustomConfiguration() : value;
        }
    }

    //service which should be override by subclass
    public virtual string SomeSetting { get; }
}

//Local Default
class DefaultCustomConfiguration : CustomConfiguration
{
    public override string SomeSetting
    {
        get { return "setting"; }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
CustomConfiguration.Current.SomeSetting;
```

---

There are other [DI Patterns](https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/introduction-to-dependency-injection/) that could be used, but require changes to the class that need it. If Configuration is a cross cutting concern Ambient Context could be the best fit.

**Constructor Injection Example**

```
public SomeClass(IConfiguration config)
{
}
```

**Property Injection**

```
public SomeClass()
{
   IConfiguration configuration { get; set; }
}
```

**Method Injection**

```
public SomeClass()
{
   public void DoSomethingNeedingConfiguation(IConfiguration config)
   {
   }
}
```

There is also Service Locator, but Service Locator is (IMO) an [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Comment: Oh that's a cool solution, I think that would work. Another one I thought about after posting this question is to split the "ConfigurationHandler" into multiple interfaces - one with the load/save method and one with the property(or a get method). That way other classes can require just the interface with the property and never access load/save. But the ambient context maybe is a better solution?

Comment: You really shouldn't use static with dependency injection

Comment: Depends what your priorities are tbh, out of the 4 main DI patterns, Ambient Context is the one that would do the least "damage" to your application, as it would just be there when you need it.

Comment: Configuration can be injected too. Will post a possible solution soon that do not use static keyword anywhere

Comment: @Tseng Ofc, anything can be injected, its about choosing the right tool for the job :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration is static (read: It's only read during startup of your application, such as from `project.json` or `Web.Config`), you can also set it during app startup/the composition root.

The new ASP.NET 5 uses it heavily and it works very well. Basically you will have an `IConfiguration<T>` interface and a POCO class, which you set up during the app startup and can resolve/inject it into your services.

```
public interface IConfiguration<T> where T : class
{
    T Configuration { get; }
}
```

And it's default implementation

```
public interface DefaultConfiguration<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly T configuration;
    public T Configuration { 
        return configuration;
    }

    public DefaultConfiguration<T>(T config) 
    {
        this.configuration = this.configuration;
    }
}
```

And your POCO class

```
public class AppConfiguration 
{
    public string OneOption { get; set; }
    public string OtherOption { get; set; }
}
```

In your composition root, you would then register it, like

```
// read Web.Config
Configuration rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);

container.AddSingleton<IConfiguration<AppConfiguration>>(new DefaultConfiguration<AppConfiguration>(
    new AppConfiguration
    {
        OneOption = rootWebConfig.AppSettings.Settings["oneSetting"],
        OtherOption = rootWebConfig.AppSettings.Settings["otherSetting"],
    })
);
```

And finally, all you have to declare in your services is

```
public class MyService : IMyService 
{
    public MyService(IUserRepository, IConfiguration<AppConfiguration> appConfig) 
    {
        ...
        if(appConfig.OneOption=="someValue") {
            // do something
        };
    }
}
```

Finally you can make this a bit easier to configure, if you write an extension method like

```
public static class MyContainerExtension 
{
    public static void Configure<T>(this IMyContainer container, Action<T> config) where T : class, new()
    {
        var t = new T();
        config(t);
        container.AddSingelton<IConfiguration<T>>(t);
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is

```
container.Configure<AppConfiguration>(
    config => 
    {
        config.OneOption = rootWebConfig.AppSettings.Settings["oneSetting"],
        config.OtherOption = rootWebConfig.AppSettings.Settings["otherSetting"],
    })
);
```

to set it up

Comment: This is a good one but sadly my configuration is not read at the start of the application. It's read/created when a user create/open a new project (and after the injections) and it can change many times. I guess this make this solution impossible to use in this case?

Comment: Good implementation of a constructor based solution :-)

Comment: Well, you can initialize your default configuration in the composition root and once you create the project, you just update the configuration values. Since it's registered as singleton, the configuration object will stay alive for the duration of the container